# Lambda in Stream.map/filter not called

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I'm trying to find separate the duplicates and non-duplicates in a `List` by adding them to a `Set` and `List` while using `Stream.filter` and `Stream.map`

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "foo", "baz", "foo", "bar");

Set<String> distinct = new HashSet<>();
List<String> extras = new ArrayList<>();

strings
  .stream()
  .filter(x -> !distinct.add(x))
  .map(extra -> extras.add(extra));
```

At the end of this, I expect `distinct` to be `[foo, bar, baz]` and `extras` to be `[foo, foo, bar]`, since there are 2 extra instances of `foo` and 1 of `bar`. However, they are both empty after I run this.

The lambdas given to the stream are never being called, which I verified by trying to print inside `map`:

```
.map(extra -> {
  System.out.println(extra);
  return extras.add(extra);
})
```

This doesn't work when I try to use `put` with `Map` either. What am I doing wrong?

---

Note: There may be other questions similar to this, but I'm looking for a kind of canonical answer for why this sort of stuff doesn't work with Java 8's Streams. If you can make this a more general question (even if it means completely changing it), I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both [`Stream#filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) and `Stream#map` are intermediate operations, which means that they are evaluated lazily. According to the documentation:

> Intermediate operations return a new stream. They are always lazy; executing an intermediate operation such as filter() does not actually perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream that, when traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the given predicate. Traversal of the pipeline source does not begin until the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed.

In any case, you should be using the appropriate methods to avoid errors like this; `forEach` should be used instead of `map` here as [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) is used to convert the stream to the result of calling the mapping function on each element, while [`Stream#forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) is used to iterate over it.

Demo: https://ideone.com/ZQhLJC

```
strings
  .stream()
  .filter(x -> !distinct.add(x))
  .forEach(extras::add);
```

Another possible workaround is to perform a terminal operation like `.collect` to force the filter and map to be applied.

```
strings
  .stream()
  .filter(x -> !distinct.add(x))
  .map(extra -> extras.add(extra)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you are going to use `.collect`, you might as well use the collected list as `extras` to avoid wasting time and space.

```
List<String> extras = strings
  .stream()
  .filter(x -> !distinct.add(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code does not work, because the stream is not consumed. You have provided only the intermediate operations, but until you call a terminating operation like `forEach`, `reduce` or `collect`, nothing you have defined in your stream will be invoked.

You should rather use `peek` to print the elements going through the stream and `collect` to get all the elements in the list:

```
List<String> extras = strings
    .stream()
    .filter(x -> !distinct.add(x))
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Using `forEach` to fill the empty collection created before is a code smell and has nothing to do with functional programming.

Answer (score 3):

In order to the filter to be applied, you need to call a terminal operation like **collect()**. In that case you can assign the items which pass the filter directly to the **extras** list instead of use **map** function.

Try something like this:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "foo", "baz", "foo", "bar");

Set<String> distinct = new HashSet<>();

List<String> extras = strings
                     .stream()
                     .filter(x -> !distinct.add(x))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually wanted a general answer instead of one that solved my specific problem, but this’ll do just fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is a more elegant way to use the `filter` with Predicate `negate()` method instead of using logical operator `!`

```
List<String> extras = strings
.stream()
.filter(((Predicate<String>) distinct::add).negate())
.peek(System.out::println)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`peek` is a function used for pipeline debugging only.