# In Java streams programming, why am I not able to set a certain field of all my objects to null?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I'm using Java 11 and Spring Boot 2.  I have a service method in which I want to set all the password fields of my User object to null.  I tried this

```
public List<User> find() {
    List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
    users.stream().map(user -> {user.setPassword(null); return user;});
    return users;
}
```

However, what is returned still contains a non-null password.  What's the proper / most efficient way to set all password fields to null?

Comment: You need to collect the stream into a list and set users to that list. Right now, you're making a stream and discarding it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62805456/lambda-in-stream-map-filter-not-called)'s a similar question I asked.

Comment: However, this is not how streams are supposed to be used, or at least not `map`. Just use a good old for loop.

Comment: You may want to use `forEach` instead of `map`.

Comment: @user *you need to collect the stream into a list and set users to that list.*  No you don't.  The OP is simply altering an object within the list, not changing the list so  you don't need to set the users to a new list.  All you need to do is start the list moving by using just about any terminal operation.  But I agree it is not a good idea.

Comment: @WJS Yeah, I wrote that sentence before realising they were modifying the elements and not just mapping them. Hence my second comment

Comment: @user.  Actually, I did too (LoL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is that the stream has not started. So you need to put a terminal
operation at the end to start the stream. Since you are changing an object you don't need to return anything.  This is not an appropriate way to use streams.

```
public void find() {
    List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
    users
            .stream()
            .map(user -> {user.setPassword(null); return user;}).count();
   
}
```

A better way is to do the following which simply iterates over the list setting the password to null.

```
userRepository.findAll().forEach(s->s.setPassword(null));
```

Comment: This contradicts the code in question since the method now is `void` instead of returning the actual users list and the last of your suggestion wouldn't really be very effective once you revert to the same return type as in the question.